# Android viewpager as like carousel

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

In my android application i have used viewpager, but i need to change the view of viewpager as like below

[image]

My Adapter

```
 pager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
                @Override
                public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                    // do transformation here
                    // page.setRotationY(position * -40);
                    final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
                    page.setScaleX(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.4f);
                    page.setScaleY(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.4f);

                }
            });

            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                       pager.setCurrentItem(position);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                        int arg2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                }
            });
```

can anyone suggest how to achieve this
All answers are most welcome